# Ambiguous Expectation value

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, probability

I saw this problem on website (I wont be using the exact wording or mention the website),

> Suppose a kid gets his pocket money on the 15th of every month,
>   according to which day is it on that date, Lets say he gets 1 coin on
>   Monday, 2 coins on Tuesday...7 coins on Sunday. What is the Expected
>   number of coins he will get on the 15th of a random month?

At first i though the probability of each would be 1/7 so the answer should be 4, but it said Wrong answer.

Then thought a bit more about how to choose a random month and remembered that the calendar repeats itself after every 400 years, so thought maybe it has something to do with that, so i wrote the following code :

```
int Date(int mn,int yr)
{
    if( ( yr%400==0 || (yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0) ) && mn==2)
        return 29;
    if(mn==2)
        return 28;
    if(mn==4 || mn==6 || mn==9 || mn==11)
        return 30;
    return 31;

}

int main()
{
    double coins=0;
    int wk=0;

    for(int yr=1;yr<=400;yr++)
    {
        for(int mn=1;mn<=12;mn++)
        {
            for(int dt=1;dt<=Date(mn,yr);dt++)
            {
                if(dt==15)
                    coins += wk%7 +1;
                wk++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<setprecision(10)<<coins/12/400;
}
```

Output -

```
4.001666667
```

And BINGO! Correct Answer!
But on thinking a bit more about it, I realized that i choose Monday to be the starting day, But couldn't it be any day?
So I made this little change in program -

```
int main()
{
    double total=0;

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        int wk=i;
        double coins=0;
        for(int yr=1;yr<=400;yr++)
        {
            for(int mn=1;mn<=12;mn++)
            {
                for(int dt=1;dt<=Date(mn,yr);dt++)
                {
                    if(dt==15)
                        coins += wk%7 +1;
                    wk++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<setprecision(10)<<coins/12/400<<endl;
        total += coins;
    }

    cout<<endl<<setprecision(10)<<total/7/12/400;
}
```

Output-

```
4.001666667
3.998333333
4.000833333
3.998958333
4
4.001041667
3.999166667

4
```

Soooo...now am really confused...should we just take it 4.00666 'cause it was Monday on 1st Jan 0001 or the question could have any answer or am I missing something very important here?

What should be the correct answer for this?
If no "*correct*" answer exists, then what do you think should be the most appropriate one?

Comment: Random month of what? This year? Any year (uniform probability) in a given interval, or to eternity? Maybe you are not quoting the relevant bits, maybe the whole exercise is underspecified and cannot be solved.

Comment: @ArneVogel The question just says "random month" , it doesn't describe anything about from where was the random month is being chosen, i guess it has to be taken as eternity only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done all the necessary thought work and more; but you've over-generalised.

> I realized that i choose Monday to be the starting day, But couldn't it be any day?

No, not if the question is set in this universe.

> should we just take it 4.00666 'cause it was Monday on 1st Jan 0001

'1st Jan 1' isn't really a well-specified year, since neither the Gregorian nor even the Julian calendar existed then.

> or the question could have any answer or am I missing something very important here?
>
> What should be the correct answer for this?

The question has only one correct answer, `4.001666`, because of how the weekdays line up with the years **in this universe**. 1 Jan 1900 (we can start a 400-year cycle anywhere we like so long as it's after the adoption of the Gregorian calendar) was a Monday, so update the code in your *first* `main` from

```
for(int yr=1;yr<=400;yr++)
```

to

```
for(int yr=1900; yr < 1900+400; yr++)
```

and you will straight away get **the** correct answer.

---

As has been identified, the particular way in which the weekdays line up with the years is what drives the variance in 'potential' answers here. The same thing is behind why [the 13th of the month is more likely to fall on a Friday than on any other day of the week](http://www.furrfu.com/magpies/friday_13.html).

Comment: You said we can pick ANY starting date as long as it's after the adoption of the Gregorian calendar, then that means the date could also start from some other day instead of Monday and the answer would be different

Comment: We can pick any date but then you have to set the initial value of `wk` to be correct for that date! I picked 1 Jan 1900 since, it being a Monday, it meant no other code had to change. Had I picked 2 Jan 1900, `int wk=0;` would have had to be changed to `int wk=1;` ...

Comment: Ahhh....yes ofcourse! Thanks AakashM...should've thought of that myself! big logical mistake on my part...

Answer (score 2):

Your extended results can only be explained by the weak days not being equally distributed over the months within a 400 year period.

This is related to the fact that week days repeat on a 7-based cycle wheras leap years repeat on a 4-based cycle (with extensions) and months are not equally long either, so although the calendar repeats after 400 days, there might quite well be some dependency on the start day you choose (and apparently *is*).

We can have this more easily, though: You have 400 years with 12 month each, i. e. 3600 month. 3600 is not dividable by 7, so the week days *cannot* be equally distributed over the months, so you *must* get some difference depending on the chosen start day...

Problematic now are these two lines within the outermost for loop:

```
int wk=i;
for(int yr=1;yr<=400;yr++)
```

You set the start day to any arbitrary value out of [0..6] for some *specific* year. However, only one of these 7 values actually matches the year selected, the other 6 ones define some fantasy calendars (the day of your birth is fix, find out whichever it was - and then imagine you vary it to all the other days of the week...).

Side note: actually, you used the Gregorian calender (the calculations are based on) backwards from when it has been introduced, doing so, you'd have to calculate the correct start day for year 1, too. By accident it must have (virtually) been a Monday, too, so that you got the correct result by luck...

Comment: Yes that sure was the problem with my code, i didn't realize that even after thinking about it for hours! (maybe i was just too over-confident that my answer is correct or was too dumb to overlook this important fact). Its only now that i feel how dumb were my arguments!  Thanks for your help anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

> Soooo...now am really confused...should we just take it 4.00666 'cause it was Monday on 1st Jan 0001

Yes, although of course our current calendar system wasn't in use at that time. If you pick another start day, you'd be doing the calculation for some other calendar system than what we actually use.

Note that Jan 1 1, Jan 1 401, Jan 1 801, Jan 1 1201, etc. are all the same day of the week (again in our current calendar system). You don't have to pick year 1 specifically, but you have to pick the start of whichever 400-year period you choose.